# zabbix server and huge databse files

Tags: mysql, database, server, zabbix, zabbix-custom-reports

i have Zabbix server with mariadb database,today both ( zabbix and databadse ) services has fail and i found that the root partition had no storage remain . i sort database files with size and the result :

```
12G     /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/trends_uint.ibd
8.9G    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/events.ibd
8.8G    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/trends.ibd
6.3G    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/history.ibd
6.1G    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/history_uint.ibd
2.9G    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/event_recovery.ibd
168M    /var/lib/mysql/zabbix/history_str.ibd
```

and df -h command :

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1      xfs        50G   50G  352K 100% /
```

how can i delete this files and start services ?
thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about supporting zabbix as a product, not about programming!

Answer (score 0):

If you delete these files, you break Zabbix. Expand the partition if you can. Depending on how long your data retention is, a Zabbix database can grow quite large. Using PostgreSQL and Timescale DB can help in reducing space occupancy.

If you really want, delete folder `/var/lib/mysql/zabbix/`, restart the database service, and create a new zabbix database. All your Zabbix configuration and metrics data will be lost.

Comment: thanks for your reply . i try to delete this files by date and let you know .